# Consider the set $S = \{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j\}.$ How many $4$-element subsets of S contain neither a nor b?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I understand most of the concept for set and subsets however, I do not understand the logic here.

Question : Consider the set $S = \{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j\}.$ How many $4$-element subsets of S contain neither a nor b?

Solution: $\binom 84= 70$

I don't know where does the 4 comes from...

Comment: $4$ comes from the "..4-element subset .." and $8$ from $10$ elements ninus the $2$ excluded

Comment: Ho yeah sorry it's my mistake!

Comment: Enumeration problems should be tagged combinatorics rather than probability.

Answer (score 1):

Combination formula
$$C_{p}^{n} = \frac{A_{p}^{n}}{p!} = \frac{n!}{p!(n-p)!}$$
In your situation $p$ is the $4$ element subset, you replace each unknown in the general formula by its value and you get $70$ as an answer.